# Embed SIGAR .so and .dll files into OSGI bundle

Tags: maven, osgi, karaf, sigar

I would like to embed .so files and .dll files into OSGI bundle. I tried this:
I copied all files into `src\main\resources\lib`

Then I added this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hyperic</groupId>
            <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.5.132-6</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

POM.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Embed-Dependency>sigar;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
            <Embed-Dependency>sigar;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                            <Include-Resource>
                                ${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/libsigar-amd64-linux.so,
                                ${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/libsigar-x86-linux.so,
                                ${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/libsigar-amd64-solaris.so,
                                ${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib,
                                ${basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll
                            </Include-Resource>
                            <Bundle-NativeCode>
                                /libsigar-amd64-linux.so;
                                processor=x86_64; osname=Linux,
                                /libsigar-x86-linux.so;
                                processor=x86;
                                osname=Linux,
                                /libsigar-amd64-solaris.so;
                                processor=x86_64; osname=Solaris,
                                /libsigar-universal64-macosx.dylib;
                                osname=macosx; processor=x86;
                                processor=x86_64,
                                /sigar-amd64-winnt.dll;
                                processor=x86_64; osname=Windows
                            </Bundle-NativeCode>
            <Bundle-Activator>org.test.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Bun when I run the bundle into OSGI framework I get:

```
no sigar-amd64-winnt.dll in java.library.path
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no sigar-amd64-winnt.dll in java.library.path
        at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.loadLibrary(Sigar.java:172)
```

Can you give some advice how I can embed them?

***Update:*** I also tried this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Embed-Dependency>sigar;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
            <Include-Resource>
                ${maven-resources},
                lib=src\main\resources\lib
            </Include-Resource>
            <Bundle-NativeCode>
                lib/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll;
                processor=x86_64; osname=win32
            </Bundle-NativeCode>
            <Import-Package>
                org.osgi.framework;version="[1.7,2)",
                org.osgi.util.tracker;version="[1.5,2)"
            </Import-Package>
            <Bundle-Activator>org.test.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
         </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I get this partial result:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve io.lambdacube.osgi.sigar [31](R 31.0): missing requirement [io.lambdacube.osgi.sigar [31](R 31.0)] osgi.native; (|(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86_64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=solaris)(osgi.native.processor~=x86_64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=macosx)(|(osgi.native.processor~=x86)(osgi.native.processor~=x86_64)))) Unresolved requirements: [[io.lambdacube.osgi.sigar [31](R 31.0)] osgi.native; (|(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86_64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=solaris)(osgi.native.processor~=x86_64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=macosx)(|(osgi.native.processor~=x86)(osgi.native.processor~=x86_64))))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:]
```

Any idea for solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the header `Bundle-NativeCode` to map native library in your bundle.

Moreover, there are already severals projects packaging sigar as an osgi bundle. You can see for example [this one](https://github.com/magnet/sigar-bundle) or [here](https://github.com/kamon-io/sigar-loader)

Comment: I checked the links. dll file for Windows is missing. I tried to update my POM file but I get error Native library not found in JAR: /libsigar-amd64-linux.so. Can you give some advice?

Comment: Based upon the dir name above, src\main\resources\lib, it would seem your libraries are in the lib folder of the bundle? Have you compared the entry names in the bundle with the values in the Bundle-NativeCode header in the bundle's manifest?

Comment: I have partial progress, please see the post.